# Date comparison with primitive value. When it is bigger than primitive?

Tags: javascript

```
new Date('Sep 23, 2019') > 0     ----> true
new Date('Sep 23, 2019') > 's'   ----> false
```

When date compared with primitive is greater or lower than primitive?

F.ex. I need to compare any date with a primitive which is lower than the date.

Comment: `Date.date` is not a function. What exactly are you trying to do ? Give a little more context to your problem and reproduce it in a code snippet

Comment: Oh, sorry, typo there

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires a date object to be compared to the primitive *and* the primitive to be a number or even a string? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: its for sorting, just a safe guard. If type of value of the sorted item is not a date, I want it to be positioned at the top of sorted list. Using a Material table, so sorting function is defined by default. Just preparing data for that function

Comment: Then, it seems like you need to check if the value is date and return `-1` then, rather than try to rely on a weird interaction between types.

Comment: Actually in this comparison the method valueOf is compared with number `new Date('Sep 24, 2019').valueOf() > 0` this is what's happening

Comment: Dont want to rewrite the sorting function. Its already defined  by Material

Comment: This question should be rewritten inline with @VLAZ 's first comment about the XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `Date` is compared to `Number`, using one of the `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=` operators, the `Date` is converted to milliseconds (as if `.getTime()` is invoked on it).

When `Date` is compared to `String` like `"1569177000000"`, the string is converted to the number too.

When `Date` is compared to `String` like `"s"` that cannot be converted to a number, there is no ordering: you will always get `false` (any comparison to `NaN` is false).

Comment: When compared to a string, the date will be converted to a string, it's not `undefined`. Check my answer. So for the 23rd of September, the `date > "L"` would be true since the string you get starts with `"Mon"` and `"M" > "L"`.

Comment: @VLAZ: On my Chrome, `date > 'L'` is `false`, and `date < 'L'` is also `false`. No string behaves like that. Also, [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) never does `ToPrimitive(y, hint String)`, if I'm reading it right.

Comment: Wait, you're right. Sorry, for some reason I thought the `==` and `>` use the same algorithm to determine the value of both operands. Still, `date > "16"` returns `true` because the `valueOf` would be used in this comparison and the timestamp starts with a `1`.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, if the string is convertible to number, it works as expected; if it is not, I have no clue why it returns `false` and not `undefined`. Then again, my Chrome says `1 < NaN` is also `false` and not `undefined`. I suppose there's a step somewhere where Abstract Relational Comparison result of `undefined` is turned into `false` for the concrete relational operator, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @VLAZ Also, `date > "16"` returns `true` because `date.valueOf() > parseInt("16")`, not because `"16"` starts with `1`. Proof: for `let date = new Date('2019-09-23T12:00:00Z')`, `date > "1569230000000"` but not `date > "1569250000000"`.

Answer (score 3):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> For relational abstract comparisons (e.g., <=), the operands are first converted to primitives, then to the same type, before comparison.

Specifically, for `>`, see [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) in the specification, where `LeftFirst` is `false`.

It's pretty complicated, but both sides are converted to a primitive (preferably a number) if they aren't already. When this is done with a Date, it returns the date's Unix timestamp.

Because both sides are then numbers, it's straightforward after that - the interpreter just checks which number is larger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the valueOf function on date

```
 // Convert date into primitive
 new Date('Sep 23, 2019').valueOf() //1569177000000
```

you can use `getTime()` or `date functions` to convert date into primitive value and then use a comparison operator.